# Problema com atualização de produto

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Na *query* o objetivo é dar um update da unidade do produto, com uma *subquery* que recupera a unidade atual do banco e subtrai verificando pelo código.

```
UPDATE loja.produto SET UNIDADE = (SELECT (SELECT UNIDADE FROM loja.produto WHERE CODIGO = '212212121') - 1 ) WHERE CODIGO = '212212121';
```

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> 0 100 13:54:14    UPDATE PRODUTO SET UNIDADE = (SELECT (SELECT UNIDADE
>   FROM loja.produto   WHERE CODIGO = '212212121')-1) WHERE CODIGO =
>   '212212121'   Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'PRODUTO'
>   for update in FROM clause 0.000 sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi o que você quer mas me parece que só precisa disto:

```
UPDATE loja.produto SET UNIDADE = UNIDADE - 1 WHERE CODIGO = '212212121';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/ChangeStatus.sql).

Comment: exato cara, tinha um select desnecessário... obrigado, as vezes complicamos as coisas sem necessidade kkkkk